# WinRT and the server (ASP.NET, Azure, etc)

Tags: asp.net, windows-runtime

Has Microsoft made any indication of WinRT's current or future relationship with server development (such as ASP.NET)?

While it's been made clear that WinRT is the intended future of Windows UI programming, it also includes a substantial library of common features like networking and data processing (like JSON). If these libraries are to the future of Windows development, it seems to me like it's only natural that they will eventually move into the world of server development (WinRT is already supported by "Server 8").

(I realise that ASP.NET isn't going anywhere and that MVC, for example, could potentially be completely gutted without affecting the programming model. I'm just curious)

Comment: WinRT is supported by server 8? In what way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most WinRT APIs are only usable inside Metro style apps.  ASP.Net or any server programming for that matter, is done in the context of a desktop application.  Thus a large amount of WinRT is not usable there.  If you look at the [WinRT reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), you will see that most of what is present is aimed at consumer apps, not server applications.

Microsoft has not said what will happen in the future, but for Windows 8/Server 8 WinRT is not aimed at server development.